# Python: prevent mixed tabs/spaces on module import

Tags: python, whitespace, indentation

I know you can ensure pure tabbed/spaced code by calling Python with `-tt`. However, when I have no control over the top-level call, can I still enforce this behaviour on the modules that are loaded by my script?

Comment: It's an interesting question but ... why do you care? Are you talking about importing 3rd party packages and modules, or ones of your own? If he former, then there's little point in it - if the code parses, the import will succeed regardless of whitespace issues. If the latter, you have complete control over the formatting and it should never be an issue. The only way it might matter is if you are using the AST package to parse the imported module.

Comment: It's an educational setup. Students modify a given Python module, which they can test themselves by calling an evaluation script that imports their module. Since modifying an existing module often leads to inconsistent whitespace, and since this sometimes produces counter-intuitive error messages, I thought it would be a good idea to give them a clear hint of what's going wrong.

Comment: Then just open those files as text and check for inconsistent indentation yourself.

Comment: It's not about me correcting the submissions, @poke, it's about preventing programming beginners from spending hours in debugging the wrong errors.

Comment: You run the risk of anything in the stdlilb (or installed later) angering python. Perhaps have the students run `pep8.py` instead? That's a common industry practice.

Comment: @lenz I understood your situation but if you have the control over the initial script, then you can still perform such a check yourself first—before importing the script.

Comment: @poke, ah, sorry, now I understand... by "yourself" you mean the script :-), not me myself as a tutor.

Comment: thanks, @tdelaney, I'll have a look into `pep8.py`. What do you mean by "angering python"?

Comment: I just meant that if `-tt` requires strict conformance of all loaded modules, you are likely to find modules that your students haven't touched but don't pass the test.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only a problem in python 2. This is because python 3 *never* allows mixing of spaces and tabs. You could avoid this problem entirely if you can switch to using python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have control about the initial script, then you can just add a check for it yourself. For example, instead of just importing your student’s script, you could have a function that first checks the module for indentation errors, and *then* imports it:

```
# instead of
import foo
foo.bar()

# you have something like
foo = verifyAndImport('foo')
foo.bar()
```

And the `verifyAndImport` would look like this:

```
import importlib
def verifyAndImport (moduleName):
    with open(moduleName + '.py') as f:
        # TODO: logic to verify consistent indentation

    return importlib.import_module(moduleName)
```

---

An alternative solution would be to have your initial script launch the *actual* script in a new Python process, with the `-tt` argument. But as tdelaney pointed out, this may cause errors that are not caused by your students.

Comment: See the [`tabnanny` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tabnanny.html) for code to check tab consistency. :-)